# Question with regard to vanadurga mahavidya pancasati

Tags: mantras

samudrah uttere teere
satasringa sataaksharah
tanme buktam ca peetam ca
tanme agastyo jarishyatu
... i found this mantra in vanadurga mahavidya pancasati. can anybody give me the source and meaning of this mantra?